# Django how to check if a table is being used as a foreignkey of another table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So, I have two models, `Order` and `Orders`, and for each item that I have in my session(cart)
Im creating an Order_object(saving in database) and after each item is saved I want to do a check for every `Order` telling which ones are not a foreign key in  `Orders`, if not, create an Orders_object than add each `Order` who is not a foreign key of `Orders` And I wish that each `Orders` have multiple `Order`

Models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
   ----fields---

class Orders(models.Model):
 order = models.ManyToManyField(Order)

 ----other fields ------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
order_all = Order.objects.all()
orders_all = Orders.objects.all()
for order_object in order_all:
    the_order_object_is_not_fk_in_orders = True
    for orders in orders_all:
        for orders_order_object in orders.order.all():
          if orders_order_object == order_object:
            the_order_object_is_not_fk_in_orders = False
            break
    if the_order_object_is_not_fk_in_orders == True:
        #do something
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that :

```
order = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=pk)
for order_object in Order:
    if order_object.orders.exists():
       # Do something
     else:
       # Do something
```

Comment: Does not work: ‘Order’ object has no atribute ‘orders’

Comment: Order table does not have a orders field, only orders have a order field